# Pushing new value to an array still returns empty - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this block of codes in my controller..

```
controller('ChallengeCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.challenged = [];

    $scope.checkVideo = function (video) {
        var response;
        console.log(url);
        return $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            return data;
        }).error(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }

    $scope.challengeMe = function() {
        $scope.checkVideo($scope.selectedVideo).then(function(data){
            $scope.challenged = data.data;
            console.log($scope.challenged); //working
        });
    }

    $scope.printChallenge = function() {
        console.log($scope.challenged); //not working, returns [] null
    }
});
```

I assigned the value of `$scope.challenged` when i call `challengeMe()` function and I tried to console out the values inside `$scope.challenged` array on my `printChallenge()` function, but it returns to be null.

Comment: Try to close the `.then` with `});` not just `}`. It will throw an error if you will not end it properly.

Comment: oh, a typo, its actually closed with `});` in my actual code. thank for pointing out..

Comment: Did you get any log error?

Comment: This entirely depends on when / where you call `printChallenge()`. It's always going to log an empty array until `challengeMe()` calls `checkVideo`, waits for the async resolution and re-assigns `$scope.challenged`

Comment: Also, your `success` and `error` calls are mostly redundant. In fact, your `error` handler will make the error response look like a success in a promise chain. You might as well just leave it as `return $http.get(url);`

Comment: the flow is I call `challengeMe()` then follows by `printChallenge()`

Comment: Try to log the `data` before the return and see if it's not empty.

Comment: I have and it has values inside...

Comment: I did not get any log error @AlbertoI.N.J.

Comment: Thanks for quick response everyone :) The one who answered about `$scope.$apply` helped the problem. Seems he deleted his answer when I'm about to click it as correct answer. lol

Comment: Did you read the part in my comment where I said *"...waits for the async resolution..."*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Plz show us where you are calling the methods ?

Comment: @Phil  im getting this error after I put `$scope.$apply()` `$digest already in progress` .. I'll read the link, thanks, this will be helpful.

Comment: @slverstone that's because `$scope.$apply()` is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are calling `challengeMe()` and `printChallenge()` on page load, the problem is happening because `challengeMe()` has a async function call which populates data in `$scope.challenged`. While that async call is in progress you are executing your function ie `printChallenge()` with no time delay and since the call is not yet complete in `challengeMe()`, so `$scope.challenged` is not populated with any data.

To solve this problem you can either add a `$timeout`or you can log your value the way you have done it in `challengeMe()`

Answer (score 0):

Since ChallengeMe() is an async function, you need a timer function before you call PrintChallenge() method so that you wait until the data populates (Which is a wrong way to do as generally we don't know after how much time we would be having the data populated) OR may be you can have a WHILE loop just after the ChallengeMe() call and just before the PrintChallenge()Call. In the WHILE loop you can check whether $scope.challenged is not NULL.

The console message inside the .then inside the ChallengeMe() method works because .then executes only after the AJAX call has finished. But by this time the execution must have moved further to the PrintChallenge() method without waiting for the Data and thus the console message inside the PrintChallenge() callhas nothing.